# SQL traversal issue without duplicate data

Tags: sql, sql-server

i got a dataTable for the menu info

```
Id  P_ID  Name
1   null  Main
2   1     menu1
3   1     meun2
4   1     menu3
5   2     menu1_1
6   5     menu1_1_1
7   3     menu2_1
8   4     menu3_1
```

when i got id 6 ,7
how can i get the data like that

```
Id  P_ID  Name
1   null  Main
2   1     menu1
3   1     meun2
5   2     menu1_1
6   5     menu1_1_1
7   3     menu2_1
```

and without duplicate data

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What's the logic that excludes Id 4 and 8? I don't see any duplicate rows in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This produces your expected result, assuming that what you want to find is the rows you're searching for and all parents, and wish to exclude any siblings:

```
declare @t table (ID int,P_ID int,Name varchar(20))
insert into @t(Id,P_ID,Name) values
(1,null,'Main'),
(2,1   ,'menu1'),
(3,1   ,'meun2'),
(4,1   ,'menu3'),
(5,2   ,'menu1_1'),
(6,5   ,'menu1_1_1'),
(7,3   ,'menu2_1'),
(8,4   ,'menu3_1')

declare @search table (ID int)
insert into @search (ID) values (6),(7)

;With AllParents as (
    select ID,P_ID,Name from @t where ID in (select ID from @search)
    union all
    select t.ID,t.P_ID,t.Name from @t t inner join AllParents ap on t.ID = ap.P_ID
)
select distinct * from AllParents
```